# netbeans using terminal window

Tags: node.js, netbeans, terminal

[image]

Above is the image from netbeans terminal window. I want to use it to check the version of nodeJS.

Problem is when i click on the computer icon(single) to use the terminal so I can type it just refresh.

[image: image1]

It becomes like above then after 1 sec returns to original state. I cant type anything on it

Answer (score 1):

[image: cgwin]

You must cgwin in order to resolve your issue here is link  [cgwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)